# slideDown behaviour on hover with inner divs being absolute

Tags: jquery

Here is something that I can't figure it out.

Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/MrkMZ/

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="top"><a href="#">top text</a></div>
    <div id="bottom"><a href="#">bottom text</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
#top {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
#top a {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#box').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('#top, #bottom').slideUp(300);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('#top, #bottom').slideDown(300);
    }
);
```

As you can see, on box hover the top and bottom divs slide correctly but the text inside the top and bottom divs behave differently when sliding. The top text stays while the bottom text slides down with the div.

Anyway to make even the top text slide? Or make the bottom text stay instead of sliding.

On slideDown/slideUp jQuery changes the height of the element.

The only difference is that one has top: 0 and bottom one has bottom: 0. That alone makes this weird effect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but the reason why the top text doesn't move up when the div slides up is because the text has a margin-top of 20px.  That margin stays 20px as the div gets smaller.

Comment: The effect (in Opera) is exactly what one would expect and is not at all unpleasing. A mousover animation is what the Spanish flag has always needed.

Comment: @scott.korin margin-top has nothing to do with it. Remove it and try and the text will still stay and not slide.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot The effect in Opera is the same as in Chrome, the text in the top div does not slide while the text in the bottom div does slide.

Comment: Crusty, browsing your fiddle in Opera I see what we might term a "center-split slide" effect; on mouseover, #top slides up, #bottom slides down, revealing full height yellow background; on mouseout, #top and #bottom slide back into the frame to restore the "Spanish flag" appearance.

Comment: However, #top and #bottom give slightly different visual effects as they slide; #top, text remains static as its div collapses; #bottom, text slides down as its div collapses. This is what you would expect as the rule for both #top and #bottom is the same - text remains equidistant from the top of its div. If you want #bottom's effect to be a perfect mirror-image of #top's, then you need to write a custom animation for it - one involving `.animate('top', ...)`, not `.slideUp()`.

Comment: Aye, had a felling that it's because of the top of its div and the text position to it.

Yeah, animate will be the solution.

Just thought that there might be some other solution I don't know, had to ask. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I have updated your fiddle, i guess this is what you are looking for, I did `margin-top:30px` for `a` tag http://jsfiddle.net/MrkMZ/1/

Comment: On Chrome, I don't see any difference.  The top text still doesn't slide.